# Creating a selenium test image in docker (NUNIT, C#)

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, dockerfile

Ive written about 20 testcases in selenium which do work locally in VS Test Explorer.
Im using NUnit and C#.

Ive already downloaded docker desktop.
And after trying to read plenty tutorials, pages, videos, i still cant figure out how to make it run.

One uses Dockerfile, the other one Docker-Compose. Then theres a tutorial from ages ago and so on. It feels like, every tutorial is descibing something completely different.

My goal is to be able to upload the docker image on a linux server, to be able to execute the selenium tests there daily.
In the end id like to get a result file from the testrun on the server.

Containerization is completly new to me, but i never thought that it would be so complicated to create a simple image of my own selenium tests, which can be run on a server.

Does anyone here can provide a simple general How-To?
Or maybe someone has a good link to a newer tutorial which isnt from 4 years ago.

Id appreciate it a lot.